# Mutliple domains same application, feedback please

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph, beta

After watching the F8 keynote my company wants to use the options with the new open graph beta.

The situation:

The company is devided in 2 different sites, a record label and a artist management site.
Both sites have the same artists, but have different publish options.

The artist site publish event dates and locations to the graph API and the record label publishes if somebody listens or buys a track.

All the artist have their own domains too and will need to have all the options of the above sites, but then only for the artist itself.

Explaining the setup as mentioned above, do I need to create a app for each site to add the functionality, even though they are basically all the same?? Is there a way to use 1 app on all domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one app which hosts all the metadata pages and then redirects users when they click through the links.

I would denote one of your sites to be canonical and use it primarily. Only redirect if it doesn't have the content.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to migrate your sites so they live under subdomains of the root domain. Facebook authentication and open graph supports using a single application across all subdomains of a root domain.